# Java adjacency list implementation with a HashMap

Tags: java

I am trying to create an adjacency list class. I am trying to do that with a HashMap. Each bucket points to a list of lists with the last list being of size 3. 
Unfortunately I haven't managed to get it working. Any help would be appreciated. 
I get an error for the line of code

> uList.get(0).add(v); uList.get(1).add(capacity);
>   uList.get(2).add(flow);

```
/* Adjacency list */
public class AdjacencyList
{
    Map< Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> > adjList;

    //Constructor
    public AdjacencyList(int V)
    {
        // 0 -> [ [v1,capacity1,flow1] , [v2,capacity2,flow2] , ...]
        adjList = new HashMap< Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >>();
        for(int i = 1; i<V+1; i++)
        {
            adjList.put(i, new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>());
        }

    }

    // method for adding an edge (->node) with its 
    // - current capacity (aka remaining flow)
    // - current flow
    public void addEdge(int u, int v, int capacity, int flow)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> uList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        System.out.println("ul: " + uList);
        uList.get(0).add(v); uList.get(1).add(capacity); uList.get(2).add(flow);
        adjList.put(u, uList);

    }

    // method for retrieving a list of children to u (u->v1,v2,v3,...)
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getEdge(int u)
    {
        return adjList.get(u);
    }

}
```